# How do I use apt *without* fixing unmet dependencies in unrelated packages?

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, software-installation, dependencies

I have the `keybase` CLI installed, but the `keybase` package unfortunately also contains a GUI client which requires libadwaita, GTK and a bunch of other huge GUI things - which would massively inflate the number of packages I have installed and the amount of disk space that WSL uses. Because of this, I manually installed `keybase` with `dpkg -i` to avoid bringing in all the GUI dependencies, allowing me to use the CLI without any of the bloat.

However, that caused `apt` to stop working. When I try to install any other package, even something completely unrelated to `keybase`, I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 keybase : Depends: libappindicator1 but it is not going to be installed or
                    libayatana-appindicator1 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libgtk-3-0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

The only solution I've found is to temporarily remove `keybase` with `dpkg`, run my `apt` command, and then reinstall `keybase` again. But I don't like this solution - I want to keep `keybase` on my system. Is there a way to get `apt` to ignore these unmet dependencies? Alternatively, is there a way to have any unmet dependencies on the system without breaking `apt`?

Comment: @Nmath The Keybase CLI does not require any of those packages, and functions just fine without them. The only reason those dependencies are defined by the `keybase` package is because it also includes a GUI, which I indeed don't use. Clearly I do not have to install the dependencies, and `apt` is just being pedantic. My system is also not broken just by installing the `keybase` command.

Comment: If apt is telling you that these packages are dependent then they are dependent. If you have a problem with this, then you should file a feature request with the developers of this application and tell them you want a CLI package from them that doesn't have these other dependencies.

Comment: @Nmath I don't use the dependent features of the package, so I do not need those dependencies. This should not prevent me from working with completely unrelated packages.

Comment: @Dev whether or not you use the features of a dependency is irrelevant in *packaged* software -- the package includes a list of dependencies, and apt/dpkg MUST obey that list.

Comment: Maybe you can investigate building the package from source which would make it independent from your package manager. As far as using it with your package manager, when packaging the software, devs will define if other packages are dependent or suggested. This isn't a package developed by Canonical or the Ubuntu community, so it would be wise to review the documentation and/or support options from the software devs/maintainers

Comment: @user535733 Is there no way to override that in *any* case?

Comment: @Dev, only in the case of NOT using apt or dpkg to install the software.

Comment: @user535733 So should I just write the keybase executable to the system without using my package manager? Is that safe - should I prefer something like checkinstall?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1426199/edit) to ask a single, clear, answerable question.

Comment: @user535733 My question is exactly as asked - how do I use apt when unmet dependencies are on the system. It is not "how do I use keybase without GTK", that is a different issue. (To be perfectly clear, I am open to trying alternative solutions only if this one does not work - and, if needed, those will be separate questions, or hopefully none at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Apt cannot be used to upgrade or install software when unmet dependencies are on the system.

- "*Cannot be used to upgrade*" includes security package upgrades. Systems with unmet dependencies do **not** receive security updates. So it's unwise for most users to leave a system in this condition.

**For most Ubuntu users**, *unmet dependencies* occur when they install non-Ubuntu or wrong-version software. The problem is resolved when they uninstall those non-Ubuntu or wrong-version packages.

**For intrepid advanced users**, Apt and dpkg have `--force` (see `man dpkg`) options that allow limited overrides. These are legacies of the pre-Ubuntu era, and are rarely used today...but might be what you seek. For example, `--force-depends-version`:

> depends-version: Don't care about versions when checking dependencies.  This affects the Pre-Depends and Depends fields.

**Warning**: Force should be used with great care and only temporarily until an upstream release fixes the dependency problem. Apt and dpkg may continue to complain strenuously (and correctly!) about wrong-version packages. Other side-effects may occur.

- DON'T use forced packages as a permanent solution. It will end in tears and a broken system. If you need a permanent non-deb-package solution, look into building from source, alternative applications, and/or alternative packaging methods. DON'T release-upgrade a system with forced packages installed, as those packages may cause the release-upgrade to fail spectacularly.

Comment: Hmm, the flag you mention doesn't seem to exist on my system (20.04) - `apt` says `E: Command line option --force-depends-version is not understood in combination with the other options`. I've tried `sudo apt --force-depends-version install mosh`, `sudo apt install --force-depends-version mosh` and `sudo apt install mosh --force-depends-version`. FWIW `--force` also does not seem to exist. (`mosh` is just an example package I'm trying to install despite unmet dependencies happening to exist on my system.)

Comment: Yes, it's deliberately obscured in the answer because fools and bots sometimes just copy/paste and hit Enter...and forcing is *dangerous*. Review the referenced manpage and you will quickly figure it out.

Comment: Ah, so ignoring unmet dependencies is a `dpkg` option, not `apt`. So there is no longer any way to get `apt` to automatically fetch a package from the repositories for me - because there are unmet dependencies on the system, so now I'm in "no man's land" - so from now on I have to force-install every package manually? Yes, that does indeed sound like it will cause a terribly broken system.